# Accessing vscanf etc from Swift Open Source edition

Tags: swift

I know `import CoreFoundation` provides C functions like vscanf(). So I can use `withUnsafePointer(&n){vscanf("%d",getVaList([COpaquePointer($0)]))}`.

However, in Open Source edition, according to stdlib/public/core/VarArgs.swift, I see `#if _runtime(_ObjC)`, which means getVaList() is available only on OSX edition.

Could you tell me alternative methods to use vscanf/scanf etc?

Note: I know `NSString(data:stdIn.availableData。 encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding)` and NSScanner combo, but I'm reluctant to use `availableData` (aka. readAll) stuff. These ways of alternative methods are also welcomed.

Comment: There looks like another problem: `error: cannot convert value of type 'inout Int' to expected argument type 'inout _'` even with `withUnsafeMutablePointer`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I was able to modify VarArgs.swift to achieve withVaList() on Linux, at least (please check code part).
http://qiita.com/cielavenir/items/2598d47b97a7c9caf970